# Blocking read vs select in single threaded c++ tcp client on linux

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

I am first time writing a simple single threaded tcp client in C++ that requests some data from server and main thread should block until we receive response or failure from server. So what I am planning to do is below ..

```
write(......) // writes struct as char buffer
read(.....) // blocks until data is received or error
```

So my question is, is this approach correct? I feel there should be alternative solution available using `select` where client wil block on `select` until socket becomes readable. Can anyone suggest what would be best in this scenario and why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best is to make sockets non-blocking. select() simply doesn't do the job properly.

Comment: For a client, `select` is fine.

Comment: Use the error returned by the calls to determine if it would have blocked with non-blocking sockets then make the call again in a loop. Blocking sockets can work with one way implementations where you have simple requests from a client. Otherwise, sockets must be non-blocking. select() is quite bad.

Comment: @user123 "*The best is to make sockets non-blocking. select() simply doesn't do the job properly*" - that is bad advice. First off, the OP wants blocking semantics, so there is no need to use `select()` at all in this case. But even if it is used, it works just fine with blocking sockets, there is no need to switch to non-blocking sockets.

Comment: You didn't offer much code.  Just remember this.  data will arrive in chunks and not necessarily in the same sized chunks as what the server "Sent".  Be prepared to have your `read` call loop until it receives the number of expected bytes.  Also, use `send` and `recv` instead of `write` and `read`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I once used a select implementation where I needed to handle requests and answer. With back and forth communication between client and server and blocking sockets, I just realised that select didn't do the job properly. It would say I have data to read when I didn't. Then it would block and communication would freeze.

Comment: @user123 `select()` works fine in every implementation I have ever used in 20 years of socket programming. You were likely just using your socket I/O incorrectly to begin with and getting out of sync. But, in the OP's case, as noted earlier, there is no good reason to use `select()` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple client-side TCP conversation it's fine to use regular, blocking `write` and `read` calls - the `write` will return immediately (as long as there's space in the send buffer) and the `read` will block until some data is received (or an error occurs). The obvious downside here is that nothing can be sent while you wait to receive. This is fine with most synchronous ("[request-reply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response)") type of communication protocols.

`select` is useful for managing multiple parallel I/O operations in more complex scenarios. For example, if you have to send and receive two streams which are *unsynchronized* with respect to each other - meaning the sending can continue indefinitely even if receiving is blocked, or vice versa, then you can `select` on the socket fd for reading and writing simultaneously, and then perform `write`, `read` or both, depending on which side is available, without blocking.

Comment: Right on money. Got my answer. Thanks !